# angularjs template(from ng-repeat) and custom directive on same element issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a `ng-repeat` on a element to iterate based on array from scope. And i am also having a custom directive(to create `jquery` widget) on the same element.

Now the problem is the custom directive get compiled before the `template` from the `ng-repeat` get evaluated and hence i am getting the raw template string in widget.

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-repeat="o in arr" id="{{o}}" ui-ngrid></div>
```

**Link**
The `link` function is as follows.

```
 module.directive("uiNgrid", ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'CEA',
            priority: 999,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.nGrid(processAtrr(attrs));
            }
      }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.arr = ["0","1"];
```

Now inside my code, i am getting the `id` values `{{o}}` instead of the evaluated value.

What the reason behind this and how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-attr-id='{{o}}'` for values that come after template compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not working. I am getting as `<div ng-attr-id="{{o}}">` in the element. not evaluated.

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried fiddle [link]http://jsbin.com/zoyirozalu/1/edit?html,js,output it, it works even without ng-attr